# Prove that $\int_{0}^{\fracπ2}(\log(\tan x))^{2n}dx=\left (\frac {π} {2} \right )^{2n+1} \left ( \frac {d^{2n} \sec(z)}{d z^{2n}} \right ) _{z=0}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

**Question: Prove that for $n\in Z^{+}$
$$\int_{0}^{\fracπ2}(\log (\tan x))^{2n}dx=\left (\frac {π} {2}  \right )^{2n+1} \left ( \frac {d^{2n} \sec(z)}{d z^{2n}} \right )  _{z=0}$$**

I used fourier expansion of $\log(\tan x)$ function
$$\log(\tan x)=-2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(2(2k+1)x)}{2k+1}$$  For  $ x\in(0,\frac{π}{2})$

Which makes hard to evaluate summation.Also Integration by parts doesn't work since integrals becomes big to obtain some reduction formual.I could't figure out any other method to proceed further.

Comment: It may be useful to know that $$
\left( {\frac{{d^{2n} \sec z}}{{dz^{2n} }}} \right)_{z = 0}  = ( - 1)^n E_{2n} .
$$ This is coming from the Taylor formula and the know series expansion http://dlmf.nist.gov/4.19.E5

Comment: You can't just take the power of an infinite or even finite sum in this way. You are effectively saying that $(x+y)^n=x^n+y^n$.

Comment: Oh,I did that wrong by mistake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Famously ([using](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Relationship_between_gamma_function_and_beta_function) [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula#Known_formula)),$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\tan^{2s-1}xdx=\frac12\operatorname{B}(s,\,1-s)=\frac12\Gamma(s)\Gamma(1-s)=\frac{\pi}{2}\csc(\pi s),$$so$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\tan^{2z/\pi}xdx=\frac{\pi}{2}\csc\left(\frac{\pi(2z/\pi+1)}{2}\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}\sec z.$$[Finally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#General_form:_Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign), apply $\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{d}{dz}\right)^{2n}=\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{2n}\frac{d^{2n}}{dz^{2n}}$ before setting $z=0$.